# Hibernate one to many insert

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

As you can see I have two tables(Offer,Items) 
I have a problem with inserting Items,every time I add Offer it does not insert List of Items. Offer holds a list of items.
Here is my code:

OFFER:

```
@Entity
public class Offer{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;
private String name;
private String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="offer")
private List<Item> items;
//getters and setters
```

ITEMS:

```
@Entity
public class Item{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
int idItem;
private String name;
private double price;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="idOffer")
private Offer offer;
 // getters and setters
```

AND HERE IS CODE FOR FILLING TABLES:

```
    Offer offer=GenerateData.generateOffer();
    List<Item> items=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        Item item=GenerateData.generateItem();
        items.add(item);
        item.setOffer(offer);
    }
    offer.setItems(items);

    pDB.addOffer(offer);//DAO for adding Offers into DB
```

Offer is successfully added, but Items are not. Is it problem with mapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try putting a cascade option on the OneToMany side?

Comment: yes I added and it's working. Is it ok that I have cascade option on both sides?

Comment: cascade option define saving/deleting by reachability, so if you ever save an item and expect its offer to be updated too then you need cascade there. however this will not be the case if the offer object is already a managed bean.

Comment: Is there a way that IdOffer will not be null if don't set (item.setOffer(offer);)?

Answer (score 0):

Offer

```
 @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "offer")
private List<Item> items;
```

Item:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idOffer")
private Offer offer;
```